How to remove right and left Border of TextFormField Flutter/Dart?
Need to remove only right border of 1st TextField and only left border for 2nd TextField its overlaped.
Can't remove whole border due to validation as its required field.
enter image description here
I have tried this :BorderRadius.only( topLeft: Radius.circular(4), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4), bottomRight: Radius.zero, topRight: Radius.zero,) but its overlapping the border at one point.

you can't give one side border to textfield in flutter. but you can acheive that functionality with container remove the border from textfield wrap it with container and give border to container.

BorderSide changes with Container
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          left: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey, 
            width: 1.0, // Choose the width you want
          ),
          bottom: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey, 
            width: 1.0, // Choose the width you want
          ),
          top: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey, 
            width: 1.0, // Choose the width you want
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
      ),
    )

Use assorted_layout_widgets package to achieve TextFormField border with default validation without Container.
TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
      enabledBorder: NonUniformOutlineInputBorder(
        hideRightSide: true,
      ),
    ))


Default validation won't be applied if I use Border outSide TextFormField. Need alternative solution.

Please use this code:
                  Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.symmetric(
                          horizontal: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: const TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                            InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                      ),
                    )


Default validation won't be applied if I use Border outSide TextFormField. Need alternative solution.
